# И снова о романе

Tags: литература

Во-первых, большое спасибо всем, кто ответил на мой вопрос о романе. Но в одном из ответов я прочитала, что роман - это произведение о любовных приключениях (любовный роман). Но не является ли в таком случае выражение "любовный роман" плеоназмом?
А еще я в прошлом вопросе спрашивала: является ли любовная история для романа обязательной? Если, скажем, написано масштабное произведение, в котором нет любовной истории, может ли оно называться романом?

Answer (score 1):

Для романа в современном понимании необходимы разветвленный сюжет и значительный объем. Поэтому любовный роман - это подвид жанра, когда любовная история является основным содержанием.

С другой стороны, любовь в романе (как и в жизни) обычно присутствует. Но, к примеру, в историческом романе любовные отношения  часто служат для того, чтобы показать сущность исторических процессов через влияние их на судьбы отдельных людей.

Первые средневековые романы были "любовными романами" по факту, хотя само слово "роман" с любовью не связано, а родственно словам романский/римский. Поэтому в своем понимании жанра романа мы как бы возвращаемся к исходному (более общему) значению слова.